# Is this example of use Optionals in java 8 correct? How would you rewrite it?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, monads, option-type

I've started to use Java's 8 Optionals. and I would like to share this method, it is "code smells" example and I would like to rewrite it using java 8 and optionlas and functional (declarative) style, so I am interested in seeing your opinion on it. Let's consider this method:

```
  public boolean isTokenValid(String userAgent, Optional<String> apiKey) {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("userAgent : %s, Key ?: %s", userAgent, apiKey.isPresent()));
    if ("ALFA".equalsIgnoreCase(userAgent)){
        return (apiKey != null && apiKey.isPresent()
                && ispropertyExists(ALFA_TYPE, apiKey.get()));
    }
    else {
        return (apiKey != null && apiKey.isPresent()
                && ispropertyExists(BETA_TYPE, apiKey.get()));
    }
}
```

Where "ispropertyExists" returns boolean type, and "ALFA_TYPE" and "OMEGA_TYPE" are enums constants.
So below is the way I rewrote this method in intention to improve the readability and practice functional thinking style. I've added comments, to explain my thoughts and reasons I did so and so, I appreciate your opinions and examples of your ways if you think you able to improve it.

```
    /**
 * We should not pass Optionals as a parameters to the methods. We
 * should use Optionals only for return value when we are not sure if value will
 * be presented at the end of the calculations or not.
 */
public boolean isTokenValid(String userAgent, String apiKey) {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("userAgent : %s, Key ?: %s", userAgent, apiKey));

    /**
     * If apiKey is null then it is incorrect. And execution will stop after
     * Optional.ofNullable(apiKey), since monad will be having null value. If apiKey
     * is not null then we still want to filter out empty strings. If after filter
     * there will be no value, then execution will stop.
     * If we have some value for apiKey then it is ok and we map the monad to the
     * userAgent value to proceed the chain of calls on monad.
     */
    Optional<String> userAgentOptional = Optional.ofNullable(apiKey).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
            .map(ak -> userAgent);

    /**
     * We map "userAgent" value to boolean (if it is a alfa or not). Then
     * we map that boolean to boolean value which represents security check in db
     * itself.
     */
    Optional<Boolean> isValid = userAgentOptional.map(ua -> "ALFA".equalsIgnoreCase(ua))
            .map(isAlfa -> isAlfa ? ispropertyExists(ALFA_TYPE, apiKey)
                    : ispropertyExists(BETA_TYPE, apiKey));

    /**
     * And all in all we get value from our optional boolean. If "somehow" it is
     * ended up to be empty, then we retrun "false", if it is not empty, then the
     * value will itself be returned.
     */
    return isValid.orElse(false);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: couldn't you just combine those chain of `map`s into one and work along...besides optional as an argument is a bad practice in its own.

Comment: Ok, so your opinion is - everything is OK but just contract it to:
"Optional.ofNullable(apiKey).filter(...)
                .map(...)
                .map(...)
                .map(...)
                .orElse(false);"
is my understending correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would combine all the operations in one chained statement and return the result avoiding unnecessary `Optional` variables.

```
 return Optional.ofNullable(apiKey)
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .map(ak -> userAgent)
                .map("ALFA"::equalsIgnoreCase)
                .map(isAlfa -> isAlfa ? ALFA_TYPE : BETA_TYPE)
                .map(type -> ispropertyExists(type, apiKey))
                .orElse(false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion, how long have you been writing in functional style? Do you use other languages besides java8?(may be haskell)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you’re overdoing and overcomplicating it. I agree that in general we should not pass an `Optional` as a parameter to a method. If you cannot require the passed `apiKey` to be non-null, my suggestion would be:

```
public boolean isTokenValid(String userAgent, String apiKey) {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("userAgent : %s, Key : %s", userAgent, apiKey));
    if (apiKey == null || apiKey.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    return ispropertyExists(
            userAgent.equalsIgnoreCase("ALFA") ? ALFA_TYPE : BETA_TYPE, apiKey);
}
```

I would find this distinctively simpler. There is no need to use an `Optional` for your case.

Comment: I am completely  agree it is simpler for those ones who get used to imperative style. :) And I agree I am overcomplicating it for people who get used to write in imperative style. I like your example too. :) Thanks for opinion! And still how would you rewrite using monads? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you love functional style, first try to not use `null`, or at least don’t pass `null` around.

But if you must use `null`, here is my code for you:

```
public boolean isTokenValid(String userAgent, String apiKey) {
    final Enum type = "ALFA".equalsIgnoreCase(userAgent) ? ALFA_TYPE : BETA_TYPE;
    return
        Optional.ofNullable(apiKey)
        .filter(ak -> ispropertyExists(type, ak))
        .isPresent();
}
```

PS: functional style doesnt mean trying to put everything chained and avoid temporary values. Rather, it is about the use of **pure functions** and **immutable data**. Regardless of style, our goal is to write readable and reasonable code. Pure functions and immutable data are very suitable for that goal.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I agree that it is a good Idea to get rid of optional parameter passed into method, and I did it in my example. And I agree we should not pass nulls into methods, but with current offshore team in sunny India it is impossible, unless we rewrite whole codebase and rehire offshore team, so I am curious about your opinion in such conditions. Have you considered second example I've provided?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. So in your example you have changed the type parameters of "ispropertyExists" function, now in your example it takes "boolean" instead of "ENUM". How would you rewrite it without changint "ispropertyExists" signature?

Comment: No, I didnt change. The “type “variable is still an enum. Could you check it again.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am sorry. Thanks for your opinion.